# Looking for Coldfusion 8 Enterprise license

Tags: coldfusion

I was told to post my question here. I have a CF8 Standard license which is 32bit and need a CF8 Enterprise license 64bit. The code I have can not be upgraded to later versions of CF. Anyone know where I can get or purchase a 64bit license of CF8 without breaking the bank?

Any help would be appreciated
Gary

Comment: You could try contacting Elishia Dvorak at Adobe, and she could point you in the right direction. I don't remember who specifically you should contact for licensing. Though with a version that old, why can't it be upgraded? There have been quite a few improvements in the language and engine since CF8.

Comment: ColdFusion is notorious for having stuff break during updates. The gap between 8 & 11 could probably bring a production server to its knees. Most people can't risk that.